# How to store a phone number in c++

Tags: c++

I used the below code to store an phone number(10 digit number) in c++:

```
#include<iostream.h>
void main(){
   long long num;
   cin>>num;
   cout<<num;
} 

Input:998578985
output:1395855233
```

Why is this happening? Is there any other way to store a 10 digit number. I am using turboc++ in win7.
[image]

Comment: Don't try to store a phone number in an integer data type.  A phone number is not an integer, it's a string.  (Although this is not the cause of the above issue.)

Comment: A few hints on code quality: `#include <iostream>`, the `.h` suffix is not allowed anymore, qualify `cin` and `cout` with `std::`, use a newer compiler.

Comment: Change your compiler. This program is not standards compliant (for example, main should return int). Under GCC, this value is handled correctly.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth When i tried using string. I am getting an error "Undefined symbol string" even i included #include<string.h>. Don't know y. Can u help me

Comment: @Pramod because you should include <string>, not <string.h>

Comment: `#include <string>`, not `<string.h>`, and fully qualify type `std::string`.

Comment: If i am not include <string.h> i am getting an error unable to open include file 'string'

Comment: No. First step, get a modern compiler and editor. How can anyone work like this?

Comment: @Pramod: I guess it's a bit off topic, but why on Earth are you using a compiler from the 1990s? (This is partly relevant though, since your compiler can't find the string headers)

Comment: I am unaware of any other c++ compilers. I can't find any plugin for netbeans although it is the other one i know. I just started learning c++ 2days back

Comment: @Pramod: You won't find many people here who can debug problems caused by using a 20-year old compiler. The code works as expected with a modern compiler: http://ideone.com/zmhP3. If you want a free modern compiler for Windows, then Visual Studio Express is probably as good a choice as any.

Comment: @Pramod: [The GNU Compiler Collection (GCC)](http://gcc.gnu.org/) comes with a very popular, modern, widely used C++ compiler. It's also free (and free of charge). Since you use Windows, you might want to have a look at [MinGW](http://mingw.org/) which will give you, among other things, GCC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend downloading [Visual C++ 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express) which is free and a huge improvement over TurboC++. Most of the issues you're having is due to it being old and no where near standard compliant. For example, it doesn't have `using` (which means you have to qualify things like `std::cin`) and doesn't support C++ header files without the .h.

As for your original question: I would just store phone numbers in a string and only try to parse or validate them if I really had to. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation) for an example of parsing using regexes.

Answer (score -1):

1. simple you should use long data type it will allow you to access or accept 10 digit numbers hope this will help you.
2. otherwise make it string and allocate size how much digits you want to accept